# How to select a left joined table data as an array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display comments below updates. Please help me know how to bring all the comments as an array from the database. The code below will give me only one comment when I call $article->comments as shown below, I only get one result. Counting the rows gives a correct count, but displaying brings only one result.

```
$articlesQuery = $db->query("
SELECT 
updates.id, 
updates.update_text,
updates.posted_at,
updates.user_id,
updates.the_group,
members_comments.comment AS comments,

COUNT(articles_likes.id) AS likes,
GROUP_CONCAT(members.id SEPARATOR '|') AS liked_by

FROM updates


LEFT JOIN articles_likes
ON updates.id = articles_likes.article

LEFT JOIN members
ON articles_likes.user = members.id

RIGHT JOIN members_comments
ON members_comments.update_id = updates.id

GROUP BY updates.id

ORDER BY updates.id DESC

LIMIT 3
");

while ($row = $articlesQuery->fetch_object()){
$row->liked_by = $row->liked_by ? explode('|', $row->liked_by) : [];
$articles[] = $row;
}
```

then to display, this brings errors, but it explains what i'm trying to do.

```
foreach($articles as $article): 
echo $article->update_text; 

foreach ($article->comments as $comment){
                echo $article->comment;
}
endforeach;
```

Comment: Replace $articlesQuery->fetch_object() with $articlesQuery->fetch_array() . Then you will have all rows as an array

Comment: Follow This http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: @BikashPaul, that spoils everything else i am doing with that query, and it doesn't solve the problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the loops are incorrect.

Foreach $article (This is now 1 row)

foreach comment in $article echo comment

So this comment will only be a comment from 1 row?

Unless I have misunderstood this should be your code:

```
foreach($articles as $article) {
      print $article->update_text."\n";
      print $article->comment."\n";
}
```

Comment: This is what I did before trying to loop the comment part. The comments table is left joined to the updates table, and there may be many comments for each update. I want to pull all the comments out. If I use COUNT(members_comments.comment) AS comments, I may get a result of more than one, but how can I get all the comments?

Comment: Can you paste some sample data from that query somewhere so I can view it?

Comment: Foreach ($articles->user_id) {
print $article->comment."\n";
}

Then you are printing every comment per user id

Comment: That still doesn't work. The problem is here: members_comments.comment AS comments. How do i make it come as an array? the following brought an array:

GROUP_CONCAT(members.id SEPARATOR '|') AS liked_by

Comment: It's hard to understand this without any sample data. Sorry.